# Matching GPS locations in my database against current location

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I have the GPS locations for a particular business stored in my android application database. The android application will give me location information for current location.

How can I find the addresses of business premises closer to the current location? Please note: The GPS locations for this business is not present in Google Maps/Places.

Comment: How did you do this in the end? I'm building an Android application myself where users can add new places onto the map. I'm having trouble figuring out how to search for these locations based on the current location...

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a nicely crafted SELECT statement, along the lines of

```
SELECT long-<current_long> AS dLong,lat-<current_lat> AS dLat,name,(dLong*dLong)+(dLat*dLat) AS r2 FROM table WHERE r2<<threshold> ORDER BY r2 ASC;
```

<current_long>,<current_lat>, and  are placeholders you should replace when building the query. Note that threshold is the *square* of the distance.

Comment: Thanks. I will check this and see how it goes.